# add xsi:type in SOAP python spyne xml response

Tags: python, soap, spyne

I am using  example/complextype.py script provided in spyne official repo and I got the following
reponse:

```
--------------- RESPONSE ------------------------
 <xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soap11env:Envelope xmlns:soap11env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="spyne.examples.complex">
    <soap11env:Body>
        <tns:super_userResponse>
            <ns0:userid xmlns:ns0="user">0</ns0:userid>
            <ns0:username xmlns:ns0="user">root</ns0:username>
            <ns0:firstname xmlns:ns0="user">Super</ns0:firstname>
            <ns0:lastname xmlns:ns0="user">User</ns0:lastname>
         </tns:super_userResponse>
    </soap11env:Body>
</soap11env:Envelope>
```

what I am trying to unnderstand is how to add xsi:type attributes

<ns0:userid xmlns:ns0="user" **xsi:type="integer"** >0</ns0:userid>

```
class Permission(ComplexModel):
    __namespace__ = "permission"

    app = String(values=['library', 'delivery', 'accounting'])
    perms = String(min_occurs=1, max_occurs=2, values=['read', 'write'])


class User(ComplexModel):
    __namespace__ = "user"
    
    userid = Integer
    username = String
    firstname = String
    lastname = String

    

user_database[0] = User(
    userid=0,
    username='root',
    firstname='Super',
    lastname='User',
    permissions=all_permissions
)

   
class UserManager(Service):

    @rpc(_returns=User , _body_style='bare' )
    def super_user(ctx):
        return user_database[0]

  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server


    application = Application([UserManager], 'spyne.examples.complex',
                              in_protocol=Soap11(), out_protocol=Soap11())

    server = make_server('127.0.0.1', 8000, WsgiApplication(application))


    server.serve_forever()
```

using the provided example, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Spyne adds xsi:type only in case of ambiguity, which only happens in case of polymorphic types.

Eg. if the type in WSDL says `Vehicle` but you return a child class named `Car` AND you have polymorphism enabled in in the output protocol, you will get `xsi:type="nsprefix:Car"` opening tag of the Car instance.

If you want to override this behavior, you need to override `to_parent` function in a custom protocol and pass it as the output protocol to the `Application` instantiation.

PS: `xsi:type` tag is added when `add_type == True` [here](https://github.com/arskom/spyne/blob/35fa93f1ac34f868b9d86c639b6e7687c1842115/spyne/protocol/xml.py#L501)

Comment: your suggestion was really very useful adding as default add_type = True get the result I am looking for. I only ask you if there is the possibility of having the same result without having to patch xml.py using for example some combination of parameters for on the application invocation

Comment: Send a pull request so we can talk